# White Screen after entering mail in subscribition form

Tags: forms, email, mailchimp, subscribe

I have little issue with my subscribiton form. I have using this code into HTML page:

```
<form action="subscribe.php" id="subscribe" method="post" name="subscribe1">
                                                <input style="" class="subscribe-requiredField subscribe-email" id="" name="subscribe-email" placeholder="Email" type="text">
                                                <a style="" href="#"><button class="submit-button-2 rimu1 rimu2" id="submit-2" type="submit">Subscribe</button></a> 
                </form>
```

and this is code from **subscribe.php**:

```
<?php


require_once 'mailchimp/inc/MCAPI.class.php';
// MailChimp API Key
// MailChimp API Key ARTICLE at http://kb.mailchimp.com/accounts/management/about-api-keys#Finding-or-generating-your-API-key
$api = new MCAPI('04e62f3fa3d9bdd51XX8cd939b1abee8-usXXX');
$merge_vars = array();

// MailChimp List ID
// MailChimp List ID ARTICLE at http://kb.mailchimp.com/lists/managing-subscribers/find-your-list-id
$retval = $api->listSubscribe( '3fc8c08XXX', $_POST["subscribe-email"], $merge_vars, 'html', false, true );
```

?>

After entering mail into form, get white screen, and mail is not send. Can someone to help me to resolve this? [Example](http://touchdowner.cz) can be seen here. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hey I am using https://github.com/drewm/mailchimp-api mailchimp api and it is super easy It can be done as simple as this:

```
require_once 'class/MailChimp.php';
$MailChimp = new MailChimp($mc{'key'});


$result = $MailChimp->post("lists/$AddToListId/members", [
                'email_address' =>$email,
                'status'        => 'subscribed'
        ]);
```

BTW in the library u are using only the first two parameters are necessary and they can be omitted rather than passed as dummies

Comment: So how to resolve issue with blank screen in my case?

Comment: Where are you getting the white screen? need more details, more sample code.

Comment: I have insert URl into first post. I get that white screen aftere inserting mail in subscribition form, and press Submit button.